# Devise - Require the user to confirm their email address on change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

After a user is registered on a rails 3 + devise app. If the user wants to change their email, how can you only allow the change once their confirm the new email via a validation link?

User Story:

1. User signs into app (already a user)
2. User changes their email address
3. User receives an email at the new address, with a link to click and validate the email
4. Once the user clicks the link, the new email is saved into the db

Anyone tackel this before? Or is this 100% custom?

Answer (score 0):

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282475/devise-confirming-after-the-user-edits-email)

It's 100% custom, you (and I) have to wait for the Devise team to implement it.